# how to use ng-show without submitting form?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular js for form validation.
I want to show error messages with ng-show when user click on span tag without form submitted.
How could i achieve this ?

Here is my code for that

```
  <form name="frmStudent" id="frmStudent" class="form-horizontal row-border" ng-controller="StudentCtrl">
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="input17"> First Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text"
                           id="idFirstName"
                           class="form-control"
                           name="nameFirstName" required ng-model="firstName" />
                    <span ng-show="frmStudent.nameFirstName.$error.required">Tell us your first name.</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">  
                    <span id="save" class="btn btn-success margin-right-btn"
                          ng-click="frmStudent.$valid && SaveUpdate()">
                        <i class="icon-save"></i> {{btnText}}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: You need to show the `span` before submit the form.

Comment: how to call ng-show when ng-click fires ? in this scenario , ng-show not working

Comment: ng-click will fire only when the form is valid, so why do you want ng-show to appear?

Comment: For a better User experience the span with the ng-show should be shown before the user can click on your ng-click span. I suggest you look into the [w3school tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp) The last example will show you how it's done

Comment: its for example purpose , i put only single input here , there are many more input controls in this form

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.  `ng-show` is dynamic, it will change as the input changes.  In this case, it's showing because the `nameFirstName` field is empty, and as soon as you enter a single character, it will no longer show.  This is exactly how `ng-show` is supposed to work,  and it has nothing at all to do with if you submit the form or don't (and in fact has nothing at all to do with the `ng-click`).

Answer (score 0):

For showing errors after the user click on the span tag you can add to the ng-show frmStudent.$submitted.

For not submitting the form you can pass it to the SaveUpdate() function as parameter SaveUpdate(frmStudent) and use the frmStudent.$valid to decide if you should submit it or not.